# Stop $Host.UI.PromptForChoice window from closing

Tags: powershell

I am working on a menu for a project at work. The below code is working with the exception of one thing.

If the code is ran and the window it opens is closed, either purposefully or by accident, the `do` loop stops and I do not get the desired outcome.

My goal is to have a foolproof way of ensuring an option is selected and not bypassed.

If option 1 is selected, the loop stops as desired.
If any of the other options are selected, you are prompted again to choose an option.
This tells me the `do` loop is working.

I am missing something and haven't been able to figure it out and I am unable to find an answer.

```
function Choose_Site {
    [int]$Script:Site_Check = "0"
    $script:Site_Title = "Please Choose Your Site"
    $script:Site_Info = "Please Choose Appropriate Site For This Machine"

    $script:Site_Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&1", "&2", "&3", "&4", "&5", "&A", "&B", "&C", "&D", "&E")
    [int]$script:Default_Choice = 9
    $script:Site_Menu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($script:Site_Title, $script:Site_Info, $script:Site_Options, $script:Default_Choice)

    switch ($script:Site_Menu) {
        0 {Write-Host "1" -ForegroundColor Green; $script:Site_Check = "1"}
        1 {Write-Host "2" -ForegroundColor Green}
        2 {Write-Host "3" -ForegroundColor Green}
        3 {Write-Host "4" -ForegroundColor Green}
        4 {Write-Host "5" -ForegroundColor Green}
        5 {Write-Host "A" -ForegroundColor Green}
        6 {Write-Host "B" -ForegroundColor Green}
        7 {Write-Host "C" -ForegroundColor Green}
        8 {Write-Host "D" -ForegroundColor Green}
        9 {Write-Host "E" -ForegroundColor Green}
    }
}

do {
    Choose_Site
} until (
    $Script:Site_Check -ne "0"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Finally` block of a `Try..Catch` to do what you want by recalling the function if the value you expected wasn't set:

```
function Choose_Site {
    [int]$Script:Site_Check = "0"
    $script:Site_Title = "Please Choose Your Site"
    $script:Site_Info = "Please Choose Appropriate Site For This Machine"

    $script:Site_Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&1", "&2", "&3", "&4", "&5", "&A", "&B", "&C", "&D", "&E")
    [int]$script:Default_Choice = 9
    Try {
        $script:Site_Menu = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($script:Site_Title, $script:Site_Info, $script:Site_Options, $script:Default_Choice)

        switch ($script:Site_Menu) {
            0 {Write-Host "1" -ForegroundColor Green; $script:Site_Check = "1"}
            1 {Write-Host "2" -ForegroundColor Green}
            2 {Write-Host "3" -ForegroundColor Green}
            3 {Write-Host "4" -ForegroundColor Green}
            4 {Write-Host "5" -ForegroundColor Green}
            5 {Write-Host "A" -ForegroundColor Green}
            6 {Write-Host "B" -ForegroundColor Green}
            7 {Write-Host "C" -ForegroundColor Green}
            8 {Write-Host "D" -ForegroundColor Green}
            9 {Write-Host "E" -ForegroundColor Green}
        }
    } Finally {
        if ($script:Site_Check -eq "0") { Choose_Site }
    } 
}
```

Your problem was occurring because closing the dialog was (I think) terminating the script. `Finally` always executes even when a script is terminated.